# Support Vector Machine library for C#

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, svm

Is there any Support Vector Machine library already implemented which I could use in my C# projects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some google searchhes and found links that could be interesting:

[libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/)

[svm](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html)

[Support_Vector_Machine](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SVM_%28Support_Vector_Machine%29_in_CSharp)

[libsvm implement](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/%7Ealgorith/implement/libsvm/implement.shtml)

[Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/)

Comment: [NSvm](http://www.ohloh.net/p/nsvm) is there as well

Comment: And also is [Accord.NET](https://code.google.com/p/accord/).

Comment: And also is  [ML.Net (Linear SVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.standardtrainerscatalog.linearsvm?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_StandardTrainersCatalog_LinearSvm_Microsoft_ML_BinaryClassificationCatalog_BinaryClassificationTrainers_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across your question when trying to find a good starting point example of a Support Vector Machine implementation in C#. If someone wants to write their own SVM, and has no desire to use a toolkit or can't use a toolkit for some reason... this served as a good reference for myself.

[kernel-support-vector-machines-example-C#](http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2010/04/kernel-support-vector-machines-for.html)