# Search a specific folder for an image that is found within a picture

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, image-recognition

Been trying Google for a while and haven't even found a start point for this problem.

I am looking for a starting point for developing a check in system. I have a large database of images of inventory in house. Very clean digital HD images with no background or anything. I am looking to do a local image search.

I will have a small temp folder with only the images of products in the current order. Then to verify that the item in employees hand is that same, I want to scan the item in real time and compare it to the images in the folder. and work from there.

I can't seem to find any documentation on any classes that can help me with this functionality.

For example say I have an image on my PC, and I print out that image to paper in a VERY high quality. I want to then be able to match the print out to the original file.

Is there anything built into .Net for this?

Comment: Check out National Instrument's Vision Development Module, which has .NET support. Probably not cheap, though. http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209860

Comment: Here' a free alternative ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596262/image-fingerprint-to-compare-similarity-of-many-images. Might not match NI's quality but it might do the job, check the demo url in the question.

Comment: Is there a need for such a complex and unreliable system, it seems to me that most companies would resolve this using a barcode system?

Comment: We don't inventory the items, we only produce them, me makes hundreds of single items. we are currently using a barcode system to scan each individual item, my idea was to be able to scan a stack and process each. seeing as how it is mostly not going to be searching a huge set of files and images for a match but mostly a single file for a match I thought I would be able to increase the reliability of the system pretty efficiently, as we know exactly what file is tied to an order we simply have to say is what is here the same as the file. Not like searching huge databases to a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past. But in my case it was a facial recognition system. It worked pretty well but you have to remember that it might not work in 100% of the cases. Visual recognition is a very complicated subject and we have yet to develop a way to have a flexible 100% accuracy system.

As to how I did it, I developped a NN(Neural Network) algorithm. This algorithm had to be trained against a specific set of pictures.

Another popular approach is to use a SVM(Support Vector Machine) algorithm instead of a neural network. Then again, you will most likely not get a result that is 100% accurate.

Keep in mind that there are many different algorithms that can be used to do visual recognition. Two other popular algorithms for facial recognition are Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces.

Sadly, I have not worked with those kind of project in .Net. But you might want to check for a third party NN or SVM library for .Net.

Here is a link to a SO thread about NN
[Open-source .NET neural network library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549811/open-source-net-neural-network-library)

Here is a link to a SO thread about SVM
[Support Vector Machine library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349998/support-vector-machine-library-for-c-sharp)